# How to paste tabular data into an HTML table

Tags: html, html-table

I have an HTML table on a webpage and can edit the contents manually. However, it would make my life much easier if I can copy the data from a file to the clipboard and just paste in onto the form. Can BHOs in IE do this? Any pointers will be helpful.

I have a superset of the data in a file and I don't want to type it all into the webpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your file can be saved as a CSV (using Excel or some other program), then you can use a tool such as the one [here](http://area23.brightbyte.de/csv2wp.php) (or write your own) to convert it to HTML.